# JSON devuelto por php , sólo accesible dentro de la función http.onreadystatechange de XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, json

En php al cargar la página , construyo un JSON pequeño,  que mando al JavaScript.Eso es lo que en un principio contiene la variable json del JavaScript.

Después hago un clic en pantalla , llamando a "inicio_pru.php" y éste me construye un json nuevo , más grande y se lo devuelve al JavaScript.

El alert que está dentro del http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200, me devuelve el  json nuevo , el grande, construido por el inicio_pru.php al hacer click y llamarlo

```
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

 json=http.responseText;
 alert (json);


}
```

Pero el siguiente alert, el que está fuera del if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200), me devuelve el anterior JSON, el pequeño que tenía antes de hacer click:

```
  alert (JSON.stringify(json));
```

En JavaScript, la parte que recibe el evento click (se pincha en un nodo del árbol en pantalla, lo cual desencadena una llamada a inicio_pru.php para que construya un JSON más grande):

```
 onCreateLabel: function(label, node,tipo){
        label.id = node.id;            
        label.innerHTML = node.name;
        label.onclick = function(){

 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "inicio_pru.php";
 var JSONstr = JSON.stringify(json);
 var t_var = tipo;
                //alert (t_var);
 var params = "callFunction=anade_rama&json="+JSONstr+"&node_id="+node.id+"&tipo_var="+tipo_var;
 http.open("POST", url, true);

 //Send the proper header information along with the request
   http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


   http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

    json=http.responseText;
    alert (json);


  }
 }

 http.send(params);
  alert (JSON.stringify(json));
```

Parte del código php (he quitado funciones y clases):

```
if($callFunction == "anade_rama") {




    $jsonString1=str_replace("\$type","type",$jsonString);
    $jsonString2=str_replace("\$color","color",$jsonString1);



    $class = NodoArbolDHTML::fromJSONObject(json_decode($jsonString2));
    $arbol1=encontrar($class);



      //Lo vuelvo a poner en formato json
      $arbol2=json_encode($arbol1);



      //Aqui los remplaces 
       $arbol3=str_replace("type","\$type",$arbol2);
       $arbol=str_replace("color","\$color",$arbol3);

   echo($arbol);
   }
  else {    
   $server = "localhost";
   $user = "adminconsulta";
   $pass = "Con,Adm6n";
   $bd = "Diagnosticos";
   $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 
       or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la conexion de la base de datos");
      $path_var='/'.$tipo_var.'/'.$tipo_var.'/'.$tipo_var;
      $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ID,Label,Resultado,Tipo FROM Arbol WHERE Objeto='". $path_var. "'";

     if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 

    {

         $id_root=$row['ID'];
         $label_root=$row['Label'];
         $resultado_root=$row['Resultado'];
         $tipo_root=$row['Tipo'];
    }

        //desconectamos la base de datos
       $close = mysqli_close($conexion) 
       or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la desconexion de la base de datos");



      $children_root = buscaren_t_grande ($id_root);



      $raiz = new NodoArbolDHTML($id_root,$label_root,$resultado_root,$tipo_root);

      $root=recorrerArbol($children_root,$raiz); 





     $arbol1=json_encode($root);
     $arbol2=str_replace("type","\$type",$arbol1);
     $arbol=str_replace("color","\$color",$arbol2);
     return $arbol;


     }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Quizás te ayude esto: http://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/2097224

Answer (score 1):

Esto pasa por la naturaleza asicronica de la `XMLHttpRequest`.

Considera esto, lee los comentarios sobre la secuencia de eventos.

```
// primero, se establece el manejador
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  // cuarto, se lanza el callback, unos ms despues, cuando se
  // recibe la respuesta del servidor
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    json=http.responseText;
    alert (json);
  }
}

// segundo se envia la solicitud
http.send(params);

// tercero se hace este alert
alert (JSON.stringify(json));
```

Por eso, no puedes usar la variable `json` despues de hacer send, la tienes que usar **dentro del callback**.

Algo así

```
// primero, se establece el manejador
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  // cuarto, se lanza el callback, unos ms despues, cuando se
  // recibe la respuesta del servidor
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    json=http.responseText;
     // alert (json);
     // en lugar de hacer alert, usa el resultado aqui adentro.
     // si es muy largo el codigo, puedes llamar a una funcion externa 
     // que termine de hacer lo que haya que hacer con los datos.
     // ejemplo:
     hacerAlgoConJson(json); // pasandole el parametro json.
  }
}
```

Hay otra opción, llamada [Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa), que hace mas fácil la lectura del código. Te recomiendo que la investigues.

Comment: Ante todo , muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta.Mira, he probado esto, pero no hace nada :